# How to stop my SpinningWheel widget by being spining on certain condition with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used  [SpinningWheel](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinning_wheel) package for spinning my image but want to restrict it by being spinning on condition.
means if we spin one time then next time should not be able to spin, we touch image should not be spinning for the second time.

StreamController :

```
final StreamController _dividerController = StreamController<int>();
```

here's my `SpinningWheel` widget

```
SpinningWheel(
                  Image.asset('assets/wheel.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                  height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.3,
                  initialSpinAngle: _generateRandomAngle(),
                  spinResistance: 0.8,
                  canInteractWhileSpinning: true,
                  dividers: 8,
                  onUpdate: _dividerController.add,
                  onEnd:  (value)async{
                    Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documnet){
                      getIsSpin=documnet['isSpin'];
                      getAbleToSpin=documnet['ableToSpin'];
                      print("getIsSpin_Update:$getIsSpin");
                      print("getAbleToSpin_Update:$getAbleToSpin");

                    });

                    if(getAbleToSpin=="0" && getIsSpin=="0"){
                     print("getIsSpin_IF:$getIsSpin");
                      var add = _dividerController.add;
                      print("add: $add");
                       DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                     // String lastSpinTime =DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(now);

                      print("Current Device time: $now");

                        await Firestore.instance
                        .collection('Users')
                        .document(uid)
                        .updateData({
                        "LastSpinTime":now.toString(),
                        "isSpin":"1",
                        "ableToSpin":"1"
                        })    
                        .then((result) => {

                          print("shruti ramnandan"),

                          print("current date time updated"),

                          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "current date time updated", backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                        }).catchError((err) => print(err));   

                   }else if(getIsSpin=='1'){  
                    setState(() {
                      getAbleToSpin="1"; 
                    });
                   print("yor are not able to spin\nTry after next 24 hours");
                   }
                   else{
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: getIsSpin+"//////"+"is False", backgroundColor: Colors.red);  
                   }

                  }
                //  shouldStartOrStop: ,
                )
```